# Parsing and converting JSON

Tags: delphi-10.3-rio

I have an issue with `TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue` or `TJSONObject.toString`

the following code does not display the JSON from Memo1 in Memo2, only an empty "{}":

```
  A:=tJSONObject.Create;
  A.ParseJSONValue(Memo1.Lines.Text);
  Memo2.Lines.Text:=A.ToString;
```

What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ParseJSONValue()` is a `class` function of `TJSONObject`.  It does not *modify* the `TJSONObject` that it is called on, like you are expecting.  It *returns* a new `TJSONValue`, which will point to a `TJSONObject` if the JSON data represents a JSON  object.  You are ignoring that return value (and thus leaking it, as you need to call `Free` on it with you are done using it).

You need to change your code to something more like this:

```pascal
var A: TJSONValue;

A := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(Memo1.Text);
if A <> nil then
try
  Memo2.Text := A.ToString;
finally
  A.Free;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

`ParseJSONValue` is a FUNCTION so it needs to be
`A:=A.ParseJSONValue...`

how stupid....

Comment: `ParseJSONValue()` is a `class` function, so it should be `A := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(...);` instead.